# How to assemble brushless motors and propellers?

Tags: brushless-motor

I'm building a quadcopter and I've received my motors and propellers.

What's the right way to assemble those together?

I'm not confident with what I've done, as I'm not sure the propeller would stay in place on a clockwise rotating motor.

I mean, if the motor rotates clockwise, will the screw stay tightly in place, even with the prop's inertia pushing counter-clockwise?

Here's what I've done (of course i'll tighten the screw...) :

[image: Motor and propeller]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. Just make sure to insert a lever into the hole at the top to really tighten the nut!

Comment: Won't it break the prop if tighten to much ?

Comment: That never happened to me. I guess you just have to find the sweet spot between breaking and becoming loose...

Comment: So I'll have to do that before each flight? oO

See this video and Blu Sky's comment :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObLIjXnV1s4

*Start by screwing on the prop adapter by hand tight. Now get out a screw driver that can go though the hole in the bullet connector. Put the screw driver all the way though the bullet connector turn bullet connecter with the screwdriver while holding the can of the motor with other hand Hold it as tight as you can, Spin bullet connect using the screw driver until till the motor can slips free thus you cant tighten it anymore with out risk of denting the can.*

Comment: Exactly. It really isn't that much work :)

Comment: Nope, but it could be better designed so you'd have to do it only once. I don't like the way it's done. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

The ring should be below the propeller. It is designed to keep the three screws in place in case some of the screws come out during the flight.

Comment: Are you sure? Seems legit, but I've seen many people putting it on top of the propeller, and the propeller actually holds the screws too.

Comment: Yes Im sure. But if the propeller is preventing them to fall out then you should be alright either way.